# "Distortions" In Faces

Tags: mesh, objects, vertices, faces

How can I fix these "distortions" in the faces around the hole?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Josh Gambrell on youtube has a number of tutorials on booleans.  He's worth a look.

Comment: if it's caused by bad topology you need to fix your topology